# explain bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --zookeeper localhost:2181 --group group1

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Can somebody explain the output of the below command:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --zookeeper localhost:2181 --group group1
```

Output:

```
Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
group1          nil_RF2_P2                     0   2               2               0               group1_nilotpal-1469374217666-b7619d68-0
group1          nil_RF2_P2                     1   2               3               1               group1_nilotpal-1469374217666-b7619d68-0
```

I need an explanation on each columns Pid,Offset,logsize,Lag,Owner.

I have only 1 consumer running currently , with the following command, then why 2 rows apperaing the the above command.

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic nil_RF2_P2  --consumer.config config/consumer1.properties 
sarkar
hello all again!!
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The columns do have the following meaning:

- `Pid`: partition ID
- `Offset`: the latest committed offset for a partition for the corresponding consumer group
- `logSize`: the number of messages stored in the partition
- `Lag`: the number of not yet consumed message for a partition for the corresponding consumer group (ie, `lag = logSize - offset`)
- `Owner`: unique ID of the running consumer thread

Furthermore, `ConsumerOffestChecker` shows a row for each topic partition. Your topic `nil_RF2_P2` does have two partitions.

Comment: Super!! Thanks a lot Matthias :)